# How to inject package private classes using Guice

Tags: java, guice

Firstly i like what Guice does however i have also like to make as few classes in my system public. All services in my system are package private w/ only the interface public. This presents a few problems for Guice if one does not use a provider. I would prefer some alternative that allows me to provide a strategy to do the following:

1. for component C
2. requires dependencies X, Y, Z
3. call this method w/ X, Y, Z to create instance.

.. repeat again for all components.

In step 2 of the above psuedo code Guice now scans for @inject annotations. If this strategy was available I could decide how id like to find my component's dependencies in a generic way.

Unfortunately Module.bind just doesnt work because it works w/ classes literals.

The strategy interface for the above might look like this

```
interface ComponentDiscoverer {
   Set<ComponentDefinition> components();
}

interface ComponentDefinition<T> {
   List<RequiredDependency> requiredDependencies(); // similar to Guice's Key    
   <T> create( List<SatisfiedDependency> dependencies ); // factory method.
}
```

1. Guice gets all components by calling a registered ComponentDiscoverer.
2. It then calls the registered ComponentDiscoverer.components();
3. For each ComponentDefinition.requiredDependencies()
4. on demand call ComponentDefinition.create

Is this any built into Guice way or third party library to achieve the above ?

**SAMPLE**

```
package companyX;

public interface Service {
   void execute();
}

package companyX;

package private class ServiceImpl implements Service {

   static ServiceImpl create( Dependency dependency){
       return new ServiceImpl( dependency );
   }

   private ServiceImpl( Dependency dependency ){
   }
   void execute();
}

package companyX;

package private class ServiceImpl2 implements Service2{
}

package companyX;

public class Factory {
    Service alpha( Dependency ){
       return ServiceImpl.create( dependency );
    }
    Service beta( DifferentDependency ){
        // boring left out
    }
    Service2 gamma( AnotherDifferentDependency);
}
```

My module lives in a different package and all creation goes thru Fatory because everything else is package private.

Comment: Guice works perfectly well with package-scope classes. Just add Guice modules to the package. Can you give an example of a class that you can't get Guice to create?

Comment: @NamshubWriter: i have added a sample at the bottom of the q.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have just one `Module` unless your application is very simple. You *should* have a module for each package that you have package-private classes you want to use in. This allows you to bind those package-private classes to the public interfaces. This is a standard practice for using Guice, and it's mentioned in the [Keep Constructors Hidden](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden) section of the documentation.

With a module in the package, you just need normal `@Inject`able constructors or provider methods:

```
@Provides @Alpha Service alpha(Dependency dependency) {
  return ServiceImpl.create(dependency);
}
```